# Are there any available SPFx web part which can allow to inject custom CSS files inside modern pages, without the ability to inject custom JavaScript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am starting this new project for a SharePoint Online tenant:

1. The client has created 10 modern pages that will be defined as templates.

[image]

2. Inside each of the 10 modern pages we need to inject custom CSS to change the font/styles for each of the 10 modern pages.

The customer is aware that injecting custom CSS to override fonts and colors might break in the future if Microsoft update the HTML elements for those pages. and the customer if fine to keep updating these custom CSS files when/if needed in the future.

My concern is, if I can use an SPFx which will allow me to inject custom CSS inside the 10 modern pages, by dynamically referencing the custom CSS URLs inside the SPFx web part settings, something as follow:

[image]

I find this SPFx @ https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss .. but the issue with this SPFx, is that the custom CSS will be applied to all the pages, so I can not apply different custom CSS to different modern pages. Also I find this SPFx web part @ https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor, but the issue with this web part, is that it allows to enter custom JavaScript's beside entering custom CSS, and allowing users to enter custom JavaScript can poses a security risk.

So can anyone advice, if what we are looking for can be achieved? which is mainly to find available SPFx web part which can allow to inject custom CSS files per modern pages, without the ability to inject custom JavaScript?

Comment: There is no such web part available in SharePoint modern experience. However, you can develop such web part using SPFx easily by combining logic of above two web parts. Create text property (in pane) to get CSS file URL & then inject CSS file on page using the code given [here](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss/blob/master/src/extensions/injectCss/InjectCssApplicationCustomizer.ts)

Comment: @GaneshSanap are you able to post the steps to create such a web part? thanks

Comment: You can start creating a basic web part as you already know, add one simple text control in property pane where users can provide CSS file URL & click "Apply" in property pane >> Then you can take this URL & inject on your page using code given in above link.

Comment: Creating a web part & posting the steps with code will take quite lot of time, sorry (I did for your last bountied question > it took more than 2 hours time > answer was not accepted even when it worked for your original question).

Comment: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor, is the webpart that is almost exactly what you need. You can simplify it to render <link tag whose URL comes from an SPFx webpart's property. Or, simply create a new webpart from scratch.

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov but the https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor web part will also allow to inject custom javascript which i do not want to have..